# Python 3 Issues

Tags: python, python-3.x, nlp, nltk

I keep getting the module error and cant figure it out?

```
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-45-dc0f046397c2> in <module>
      1 # import the Subjectivity program as a module to use the function
----> 2 import Subjectivity
      3 SL = Subjectivity.readSubjectivity(SLpath)

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Subjectivity'
```

Comment: # import the Subjectivity program as a module to use the function
import Subjectivity
SL = Subjectivity.readSubjectivity(SLpath)

Comment: The code shown in the traceback is trying to import a module or package named `Subjectivity`, but that module or package is not found in the environment of the interpreter you're running the code in. You'll need to provide a lot more details about what this code is doing, and how you're running it for us to help you. Do you know what `Subjectivity` is? That might be a place to start, in your descriptions.

Comment: This file has the format that each line is formatted as in this example for the word "abandoned"
#     type=weaksubj len=1 word1=abandoned pos1=adj stemmed1=n priorpolarity=negative
# In our data, the pos tag is ignored, so this program just takes the last one read
#     (typically the noun over the adjective)
#

Comment: data structure that is created is a dictionary where
#    each word is mapped to a list of 4 things:  
#        strength, which will be either 'strongsubj' or 'weaksubj'
#        posTag, either 'adj', 'verb', 'noun', 'adverb', 'anypos'
#        isStemmed, either true or false
#        polarity, either 'positive', 'negative', or 'neutral'

Comment: Trying to run it for a lab to find Sentiment Classification on Sentences from the Movie Reviews

Comment: We don't care what the data looks like.  That's not the problem.  The problem is you haven't installed the Subjectivity module, or it's not located where this script can find it.